# XLS transformation of XML to HTML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a simple xml file and I need to transform it into html that contains unordered list with some nesting
Here is the xml:

```
<Beer>
    <name>Guinnes Draught</name>
    <type>stout</type>
    <manufacturer>Arthur Guinness Son &amp; Co</manufacturer>
    <ingredients>
        <ingredient>malt</ingredient>
        <ingredient>hop</ingredient>
        <ingredient>water</ingredient>
        <ingredient>barley</ingredient>
        <ingredient>yeast</ingredient>
    </ingredients>
    <alcChars>
        <alcohol>4.2</alcohol>
        <density>15</density>
        <calories>150</calories>
        <filtered>true</filtered>
        <package>glass bottle</package>
        <volume>0.33</volume>
    </alcChars>
</Beer>
```

And here is my xsl file (edited):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Beer description</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>Beer:</div>
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name">
    <li>Name - <xsl:value-of select="." /> </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="type">
    <li>Type - <xsl:value-of select="." /> </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="manufacturer">
    <li>Manufacturer - <xsl:value-of select="." /> </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ingredients">
    <li>Ingredients: <br/>
        <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="ingredient">
                <li> <xsl:value-of select="." /> </li>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="alcChars | nonAlcChars" >
    <li>Characteristics: <br/>
        <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <li> <xsl:value-of select="." /> </li>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
```

Apparently somethig is wrong with this piece of code since the output file consists of the head with the title in it, and the body with only one `<ul>` element. This `<ul>` contains all the xml data, but it's not even enclosed in `<li>`.
I'm rather new to the xslt and I would appreciate any advice that will help me to get something like

```
<ul>
    <li> Name - Guinness </li>
    <li> Type - Stout </li>
    <li> Chars: <br/>
        <ul>
            <li> Alc - 4.5 </li>
            <li> Dens - 8 </li>
            <!-- etc. -->
```

from my xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of:

*"... the output file consists of the head with the title in it, and the body with only one  element. This  contains all the xml data ..."*

and your comment:  "*`<ul> Guinnes Draught stout <!-- etc. -->`*"

I assume a namespace issue.
Could it be, that you while simplifying the input XML hide a **default namespace** declaration.
If there is a default namespace  in your XML you have to add this namespace with an prefix to your xslt and use this prefix in your template rules.

If you have something like:

```
<Beer xmlns="http://www.beer.org" >
```

You have to add this url to your stylesheet declaration. like:

```
<stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
            xmlns:b="http://www.beer.orgl"
            exclude-result-prefixes="b"
            version="1.0">
```

And than use this namespace prefix like:

```
    <xsl:template match="b:name">
        <li>
            Name - <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yes, that was the solution - adding the xml namespace helped to get the html I needed.
I have only one additional question - I've read that the xslt 2.0 `xpath-default-namespace` attribute allows to avoid a constant repeating of the namespace prefix. But it gave me the "Illegal attribute" warning when I added it to my code. Has anyone tried to use it?
Thanks all of you guys for your help and tips.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a very long time since I have done anything with xsl but here goes...

When defining a template it operates from within the context of the matched node. This means the node `<name>` is the context. Change the select attribute of xsl:value-of to `.` like so

```
<xsl:template match="name">
    <li>Name - <xsl:value-of select="." /> </li>
</xsl:template>
```

You'll want to do this to all the other templates too.

Please forgive me if I got this totally wrong. I might be a little rusty.

Comment: The same applies to the rest of the templates as well.

Comment: You remembered well... this time.  However, I would suggest that if you're not sure you first verify your answer, otherwise you risk being wrong and getting a bunch of downvotes.  This site works best when people do not post guesses as answers.  Just some food for thought.

Comment: That's strange - I've revised my code but still I have this thing like
`<ul>
    Guinnes Draught
    stout
    <!-- etc. -->`
on the output.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Marc's answer, you need to change:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="ingredients">
            <li> <xsl:value-of select="ingredient" /> </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

to:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="ingredient">
            <li> <xsl:value-of select="." /> </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Normally, it is better if you use something like:

```
<xsl:template match="ingredients">
    <li>Ingredients: <br/>
        <ul><xsl:apply-templates select="ingredient"/></ul>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ingredients">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
</xsl:template>
```

This then allows you to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="alcChars | nonAlcChars" >
    <li>Characteristics: <br/>
        <ul><xsl:apply-templates select="*"/></ul>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="density">
    <li>Density - <xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
</xsl:template>

<!-- etc. -->
```

which should give your desired output.

Comment: That's a good idea, but the thing is that in the xsd file I have
`<any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>`  
in the characteristics sequence, in order to make it more flexible. But something like  
`<xsl:template match="alcChars | nonAlcChars" >`  
`<xsl:for-each select="*">`  
`<li> <xsl:value-of select="." /> </li>`  
Should work, right?

Comment: @Nick Yes, that will work. The apply-template approach is more flexible (e.g. it is easier to annotate density, calories, etc.). With the for-each approach you would need an xsl:choose/xsl:when structure to do the same thing, which is harder to read/maintain/extend (i.e. you need to duplicate the code if you have these properties on other items).